# How can I use a rest controller from a different package in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

**What's going on**

I am using Java, Springboot
I am trying to create a simple API.

I have a package called `Example`.
I have two sub-packages called `config` and `rest`.

In config is the class `Application`, which is my spring app.
In rest is the class `TheController` which is the rest controller

Currently when i run the app, `Application` and try and go to one of the get mappings i get a white label error page.

However if i move `theController` to the `config` package i do not get this error and it's plain sailing.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using an import statement.
`com.Example.rest.*` and `com.Example.rest.TheController`with no results.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a @ComponentScan on your application class.

```
package com.example.config;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class SpringBootComponentScanApp {

}
```

I personally think it's a good idea to put your configuration in a sub-package "com.example.config" and not in the parent package "com.example", but you need to override Spring Boot's default component scan for that case.

See also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot will only scan for components (controllers, services, repositories, ...) starting from the package of the application class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) and below.

So best to use `com.example.Application`, then you can use `com.example.rest.TheController` and things should work.